# Buffer overflow and dmesg on 64 bits machines

Tags: linux, gcc, 64-bit, buffer-overflow, exploit

I wrote a very simple program which has a buffer overflow vulnerability which I want to exploit. The program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void
 foo(char *asd) {
     char b [2];
     memcpy(b, asd, strlen(asd));
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    foo(argv[1]);

 }
```

When I run it:

```
./a.out `perl -e 'print "A"x100'`
```

I obtain of course the segmentation fault:

```
 [2]    4466 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out `perl -e 'print "A"x100'`
```

The thing that I don't understand is that when I run dmesg I expect to see the rip register to contain 0x4141414141414141 when the fault occurred. Instead it contains something different like ip:7fba99a4141. The last two bytes seems to be overwritten, but no matter how many As I write, no more than those two bytes appears to be written according dmesg. 
On the other hand, if I use gdb, the returning address seems to be completely overwritten and I can indeed exploit the bof. Why is there this difference?

Comment: Can you attach the assembly code produced by the compiler? That should help explain.

Comment: If you change `b` to `char b[4]`, what do you see in the register then?